# SearchBar with hidden UITableView iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I want to do a `UISearchBar` with a `UITableView` that only shows the `UITableView` when something is written in the `UISearchBar`.
Can somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a `UISearchDisplayController`. Check out the Apple [TableSearch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848) sample code

Comment: I have seen that example but it's not what I want. I want to have a normal view, without a table, with a UISearchBar that searches in a array or dictionary. The table with the filter of results should just appear when I write something in the UISearchBar. I don't know if I'm explaining it right...

Comment: You can access the tableview of the search display controller and set it to be hidden whenever you want. Look at the UISearchDisplayControllerDelegate methods to get your hooks.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've solved like you said, setting it to be hidden when I want.